# How to merge or open a color OpenType SVG font (EmojiOne) in Font Forge?

Tags: fonts, font-design, font-forge

I am trying to merge EmojiOne into a regular OTF font to give the basic OTF font Emoji support:

https://github.com/adobe-fonts/emojione-color

Typically I would open the regular OTF font, then go Element > Merge and select Emoji One. Then I could Generate Font and select SVG font for output.

However, when I try to even open EmojiOne Color in Font Forge to look at it there are no color glyphs visible and only a few "emojis" showing up at all. It says on trying to open the EmojiOne Color font:

> The following table(s) in the font have been ignored by Font Forge
>
> Ignoring 'DSIG' digital signature table
>
> Ignoring 'SVG ' SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) table

I presume this means it is ignoring essentially the whole Emoji font then?

Is there some trick to opening this in Font Forge or how do I get it to read the font and process the merge?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your "regular font" also using color? Do you want to carry-over the colors from the Emoji font or reduce the Emojis to black like classic glyphs? The more you give us here about your context and use-case, the better users can help you. What is even your purpose of integrating two fonts? Just to save a few clicks in your DTP tool? Have you considered other options like leaving the fonts and using styles?

Answer (score 0):

FontForge, as of mid-2022, do not support SVG-in-OpenType.  (Source: https://twitter.com/FontForge/status/1531784078852235265?s=20&t=Ynqs6c15IMzzrTc79YZYCA)

To merge the fonts you can instead try FontTools.  Inside FontTools there is a command line tool called `pyftmerge` which can be used to merge fonts without going into python code.